# mui useAutocomplete ignores disabled prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement my own Autocomplete component using `useAutocomplete` hook from `mui/base` package. Everything works as expected apart from `disabled` option.

My understanding is that the component should not be intractable with.
Example below comes from [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#UseAutocomplete.tsx) with added `disabled: true` option.

How can I force this component to stay closed even if the user clicks when it is disabled?

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dust-yxwwst?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1869)

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useAutocomplete } from "@mui/base/AutocompleteUnstyled";
import { styled } from "@mui/system";

const options = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 }
];

const Label = styled("label")({
  display: "block"
});

const Input = styled("input")(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 200,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#fff" : "#000",
  color: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#000" : "#fff"
}));

const Listbox = styled("ul")(({ theme }) => ({
  width: 200,
  margin: 0,
  padding: 0,
  zIndex: 1,
  position: "absolute",
  listStyle: "none",
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#fff" : "#000",
  overflow: "auto",
  maxHeight: 200,
  border: "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25)",
  "& li.Mui-focused": {
    backgroundColor: "#4a8df6",
    color: "white",
    cursor: "pointer"
  },
  "& li:active": {
    backgroundColor: "#2977f5",
    color: "white"
  }
}));

export default function Autocomplete() {
  const {
    getRootProps,
    getInputLabelProps,
    getInputProps,
    getListboxProps,
    getOptionProps,
    groupedOptions,
    value,
    popupOpen
  } = useAutocomplete({
    id: "use-autocomplete-demo",
    disabled: true, // Component shouldn't be interactable
    options: options,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</p>
      <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <Label {...getInputLabelProps()}>useAutocomplete</Label>
        <Input {...getInputProps()} />
      </div>

      {popupOpen ? (
        <Listbox {...getListboxProps()}>
          {(groupedOptions as typeof options).map((option, index) => (
            <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}>{option.title}</li>
          ))}
        </Listbox>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: how if use **readOnly: true** this result the same as you expected, the input box stay closed even it clicked.

Comment: @Eve read-only will suppress popup that's true, it is a working solution for some cases. But note that events still fire underneath, clicking a component in read-only state and then removing it will result in open popper and broken click away listener.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in `useAutocomplete` hook, although I might be wrong.

For my use case, I fixed this issue by overwriting `onMouseDown` callback in rendered input

`<Input {...getInputProps()} {...(props.disabled && { onMouseDown: undefined })} />`

`props.disabled` above is a prop passed into my custom component